# No output in cygwin using strtok

Tags: c, string, output, cygwin, strtok

I want to split and print each word of a string using this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char* input=calloc(100,sizeof(char));
    gets(input);
    char *p = strtok(input, " ");
    while (p != NULL) {
        puts(p);
        p = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

When I execute this code in online gdb compiler it works perfectly but in my IDE I dont get any output.

I use NetBeans with cygwin compiler.

Comment: What if you open a terminal window and run the program from there?

Comment: Try printing a newline after each token. The NetBeans console might be buffering output.

Comment: @Barmar it works perfectly from terminal. I also noticed that some online compilers give segmentation fault

Comment: Stop using `gets()`. It has been removed from the language because it has no ability to limit input to the buffer size.

Comment: I don't see anything that might cause a segmentation fault other than entering more than 99 characters of input.

Comment: @Barmar using "fgets(input,100,stdin)" instead of "gets(input)" doesnt fix anything

Comment: As I said, it would only be a problem if you were entering more than 99 characters.

Comment: i managed to fix it, the problem was "#include <string.h>", i forgot to add this line

Comment: Make sure you enable verbose warnings. You should have gottena warning about an implicit declaration of `strtok`

Comment: btw thank you for trying to help me, have a nice one :)